# How to combine two rows into a single row in CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am getting data in a CTE like this.

Here I am getting two records for each ActivityId, what I want to achieve is two create a single record from the two rows. From the row where r2=1 I need only the RDate as Todate, ActualProgress as endprogress and PlannedProgress as endplannedprogress because these are the only values that will changed on both the rows.

I am getting this data in a CTE.

```
WITH CTE as(SELECT row_number() over (partition by pmaph.ActivityId order by date) r1, row_number() over (partition by pmaph.ActivityId order by date desc) r2,pma.PlanEndDate as PlanEndDate ,pma.PlanStartDate as PlanStartDate,pmaph.ActivityId,pmaph.ProjectMilestoneActivProgHist_Id as ProMileAvtiID,umd.UOM_Name as UomName, pmm.MilestoneName as MilestoneName,pma.ActivityName as ActivityName ,pmp.ProjectName as ProjectName, Replace((rtrim(ltrim(Convert(varchar(12),Cast(pmaph.Date as Datetime),106)))),' ','-') as RDate, isnull(pmaph.Actual_Progress,0) as ActualProgress,isnull(pmaph.Planned_Progress,0) as PlannedProgress FROM ProjectMilestoneActivityProgressHistory as pmaph left join dbo.PM_Project as pmp on pmaph.ProjectId=pmp.ProjectId left join dbo.PM_Activity as pma on pmaph.ActivityId=pma.ActivityId  left join dbo.PM_Milestone  as pmm on pmaph.MilestoneId=pmm.MilestoneId left join dbo.UOMDetail as umd on pma.UOM_Id=umd.UOM_Id where pmaph.Client_Id=@ClientId
)
select  * from CTE where r1=1 or r2=1
```

Comment: But if I notice correctly column `promileavtiid` also changes.

Comment: Also you should share your CTE code.

Comment: Use a self-join by ActivityID when r1 <> r1 (from different tables), then pick the columns you want. Might need a filter 1 row by activity with a simple WHERE.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi yes promileavtid is different for each record because the data is coming from a history table which have its own id promileavtid. and there can be many rows for one ActivityId but i am picking only the records where date is min and date is max (2 records). I am editing my question and including the CTE Code.

Comment: @EzLo can you please explain briefly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Group By ActivityId and including a MAX(RDate) AND MAX(ActualProgress), it should return you only one-row per ActivityId.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you a hint. Make sure to keep the format of your SQL.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
    SELECT 
        row_number() over (partition by pmaph.ActivityId order by date) r1, 
        row_number() over (partition by pmaph.ActivityId order by date desc) r2,
        pma.PlanEndDate as PlanEndDate ,
        pma.PlanStartDate as PlanStartDate,
        pmaph.ActivityId,
        pmaph.ProjectMilestoneActivProgHist_Id as ProMileAvtiID,
        umd.UOM_Name as UomName, 
        pmm.MilestoneName as MilestoneName,
        pma.ActivityName as ActivityName,
        pmp.ProjectName as ProjectName, 
        Replace((rtrim(ltrim(Convert(varchar(12),Cast(pmaph.Date as Datetime),106)))),' ','-') as RDate, 
        isnull(pmaph.Actual_Progress,0) as ActualProgress,
        isnull(pmaph.Planned_Progress,0) as PlannedProgress 
    FROM 
        ProjectMilestoneActivityProgressHistory as pmaph 
        left join dbo.PM_Project as pmp on pmaph.ProjectId=pmp.ProjectId 
        left join dbo.PM_Activity as pma on pmaph.ActivityId=pma.ActivityId  
        left join dbo.PM_Milestone  as pmm on pmaph.MilestoneId=pmm.MilestoneId 
        left join dbo.UOMDetail as umd on pma.UOM_Id=umd.UOM_Id 
    where 
        pmaph.Client_Id=@ClientId
)
SELECT
    C1.*, -- Now you have all data in one row (by Activity), select whichever columns you want
    C2.*
FROM
    CTE AS C1
    INNER JOIN CTE AS C2 ON 
        C1.ActivityId = C2.ActivityId AND
        C2.r2 = 1 -- ... and join against the other row
WHERE
    C1.r1 = 1 -- pick 1 row by Activity
```